# How to put X variable estimates from many statsmodels equations as columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

The following code generates many linear regressions (all with a constant term) based on combinations of 6 explanatory variables.  The regressions and the various diagnostic statistics are placed into a df:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import itertools
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.3f}'.format

# Separate y variable from the rest of the predictors
X = df_all.loc['2019-10':'2023-02',['rsi41h_11', 'exc171_12', 'lag36a_11' , 'ljh1la_11','imp474_6', 'emp325_11' ]]
y = df_all.loc['2019-10':'2023-02',['apple_sales']]

# Split the data into training (first set of months) and test (next 6 months) sets
y_train, y_test = y[:'2022-09'], y['2022-10':]
X_train, X_test = X[:'2022-09'], X['2022-10':]

# Create all possible combinations of predictors
predictor_combinations = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    itertools.combinations(X.columns, i) for i in range(1, len(X.columns)+1)))

# Create an empty list to store the regression results
regression_results = []

# Loop through all predictor combinations and fit a regression
for predictors in predictor_combinations:
    X_subset_train = X_train[list(predictors)]
    X_subset_train = sm.add_constant(X_subset_train)
    model = sm.OLS(y_train, X_subset_train)
    results = model.fit()
    formula = results.params
    variables = ' + '.join(predictors)
    durbin_watson = sm.stats.stattools.durbin_watson(results.resid)
    skewness = stats.skew(results.resid, axis=0)
    kurtosis = stats.kurtosis(results.resid, axis=0, fisher=False)
    n = results.resid.shape[0]
    jb = n/6 * (skewness**2 + (1/4) * (kurtosis - 3)**2 )  
    jb_prob = stats.chi2.sf(jb, 2)
    vif = 1 / ( 1 - results.rsquared)
    aic = results.aic
    bic = results.bic
    condition_number = np.linalg.cond(X_subset_train)
    adj_r_squared = results.rsquared_adj
    f_stat_prob = results.f_pvalue
    X_subset_test = X_test[list(predictors)]
    X_subset_test = sm.add_constant(X_subset_test)
    y_pred = results.predict(X_subset_test)                   # y_pred is a pandas series (not an array and not a df)
    rmse = np.sqrt(((y_test.squeeze() - y_pred)**2).mean())   # convert y_test to pandas df to a series using squeeze, otherwise RMSE won't calculate 
    regression_results.append([formula, variables, durbin_watson, condition_number, adj_r_squared, f_stat_prob, rmse, vif, skewness, kurtosis, jb_prob, aic, bic])

# Create a dataframe from the results and print to a table
results_df = pd.DataFrame(regression_results, columns=['Linear Regression', 'Predictors', 'Durbin-Watson', 'Condition Number', 'Adjusted R-Squared', 'F-Statistic Probability', 'RMSE', 'Variance Inflation', 'Skewness', 'Kurtosis', 'JB-Prob', 'AIC', 'BIC'] )
results_df
```

Which gives the following table:

[image]

The regression results are hard to read.  I want to replace the columns 'Linear Regression' and 'Predictors' instead with the column names being the constant term and each of the X variables (7 new columns total) with the parameter estimates only populating if contained in the model plus the usual diagnostic stats so I have this instead:

[image]

How would I modify my code above to get this preferred output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the dataset from [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html) as an example.
If you print out type

```
print(type(results.params))
```

then it's a series.

In indexes, lines that can be turned into column names.

```
print(results.params.index)
```

And you need to know the names of all columns `('Linear Regression')` initially.
In my example it is: `'const', 'lag36a_11', 'education', 'rsi'`.

Am creating a dataframe `dfe` with empty values, outside of the loop

At each iteration, a frame `dfl` is created from the available values and joined with an empty `dfe` by a `right`-hand merge. The result is concatenated using `np.concatenate`. np.array([i]), np.array([i]) are your `variables, durbin_watson, condition_number` and so on.

The same principle applies to get the complete list of column names.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

duncan_prestige = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Duncan", "carData")
Y = duncan_prestige.data['income']
X = duncan_prestige.data['education']
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(Y, X)
results = model.fit()


dfe = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]], columns=['const', 'lag36a_11', 'education', 'rsi'])

regression_results = []

for i in range(0, 3):
    aaa = results.params.copy()
    dfl = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(aaa.values, (1, len(aaa))), columns=list(aaa.index))
    dfl = dfe.copy().merge(dfl, how='right')
    regression_results.append(np.concatenate((dfl.values[0], np.array([i]), np.array([i])), axis=0))


results_df = pd.DataFrame(regression_results,
                          columns=np.concatenate((dfe.columns,
                                                  np.array(['Predictors', 'Durbin-Watson'])), axis=0))
```